# IIS RedirectRule for an accidentally merged link

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, redirect, iirf

So I got brought in-house at a company recently, and about three years ago they signed up with a local company offering "SEO" services. I put SEO in quotes since it was about 99.9% blackhat and they got ripped off--they even got a manual spam action from Google. Anyways, I am cleaning up the mess, including crawl errors that have been coming in from these spammy links. My first step of action was to contact the webmaster to have to remove them, second to write RedirectRule(s) (site is built on asp on IIS 7.0), for links that showed up as crawl errors to get them to the proper place on our site, and third to disavow through GWT.

I am down to three links, and since I am a purist/perfecionist I want them fixed using a Redirect (having already done so for close to a thousand links). The problem I am running into is that the three remaing URLs coming from the sites has two URLS merged together: 
- domain/chicken-coop/hen_house.asphttp://domain/storage-sheds.asp 
- domain/chicken-coop/hen_house.asphttp://domain/storage- 
- domain/arenas_polebarns.asphttp://domain/storage-sheds-chicken-coop.asp

For the first two I tried using: 
RedirectRule ^/chicken-coop/hen_house.asph(.*)$ http://www.horizonstructures.com/hen-houses.asp [I,R=301] 
But I am getting a server error (HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error), same goes for the last link using: 
RedirectRule ^/arenas_polebarns.asphttp://domain/storage-sheds-chicken-coop.asp$ http://domain/storage-sheds.asp [I,R=301]

Any and all suggestions would be HIGHLY appreciated!